# TincyMCE is not defined within Django admin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django

I am using Django and have a TincyCME text editor (I actually have two, one above the other) and for some reason it won't let me click into the second one to add content.

Just wondering if this is a common problem. I'm not really sure where to look to fix the issue and was wondering if someone could point me in the right direcection.

I'm getting a 'TinyMCE is not defined' error in the console.

If you need any code please let me know.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that we were not putting www. infront of the URL. The older version of Django CMS didn't like it.